# Help with thermodynamic relation $n= \dfrac{N}{V} = \left( \dfrac{\partial N}{\partial V} \right)_{T, \mu}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

In my statistical mechanics book I ran into this relation , not sure how I can prove this.
For context, it is a chapter on the grand canonical partition function, so I tried the grand potential differential $dJ = -SdT - PdV - Nd\mu$ but to no use...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The particle number $N$ is a extensive variable. If you are looking at it as a function $N(T, V, \mu)$ the only extensive variable it depends on is the volume $V$, since the temperature and chemical potential are intensive. To get an extensive behaviour the particle number must therefore be linear in V:
\begin{equation}
N(T, V, \mu) = n(T, \mu) V
\end{equation}
The equality with the derivative trivially follows.